# How many triangles are there in the picture?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

There are eight points, connection between each other. [See figure [1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82TbC.jpg)
In addition to the red dot, any three line segments do not intersect at one point.

> 1. How many triangles are there in the picture?
> 2. If you remove three segments, maximum number of triangles left?

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: This is a complete graph. Therefore, the number of triangles should be `Binomial[8, 3]` but I haven't put too much thought in this.

Comment: Can someone make a more detailed description in proper English from this question? Especially, the section "In addition to the red dot, any three line segments do not intersect at one point." is not completely clear to me, although I have a guess what the OP could mean.

Comment: @halirutan no, it's not `Binomial[8,3]`: you can choose 3 out of all intersections that has connecting lines and make a triangle so the number should be much larger.

Comment: For the first question I think the answer is $$\binom83+4\binom84+5\binom85+\binom86=644.$$ That is, $\binom n3$ triangles with three red dots as vertices, $4\binom n4$ triangles with two red dots, $5\binom n5$ triangles with one red dot, and $\binom n6$ triangles with no red dots, where $n=8.$

Comment: @halirutan I suspect that what is meant is "No three lines intersect *except* at the red dots"

Comment: Found this sequence OEIS: https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C8%2C35%2C111%2C287%2C644%2C1302&language=english&go=Search It agrees with bof's calculation for n=8, though the formula given at oeis *looks* different. (may be the same formula reexpressed).

Answer (score 7):

**Summary**

- For the first part of question, the answer is
  $$\binom{8}{3} + 4\binom{8}{4} + 5\binom{8}{5} + \binom{8}{6} = 644$$
  The number pointed out by bof in one of hir comments.
- For the second part, if we interpret the term "segment" as one of the $\binom{8}{2} = 28$ edges among the $8$ vertices, the answer will be $583$.
  This is achieved by removing 3 consecutive edges from the perimeter of the circle. For example, removing edges $12$, $23$ and $34$ will left us with $583$ triangles.

**Part I** - number of triangles.

Let us switch to how to derive the answer for the first part of question analytically.

Instead of $8$, consider the generalization of placing $n$ red dots on a circle,
form a complete graph from them and then count the number of triangles formed by these lines. We further assume the red dots are in general position so that no three lines intersect at the same point (except at the red dots). As we can see below, this assumption is crucial.

WOLOG, we will label the $n$ red dots by $1, \ldots, n$ and they are placed on the circle in counterclockwise manner.

A triangle consists of 3 sides and each side is lying on a line formed by two red dots. Since it is possible some lines are sharing red dots, a triangle may involve $m$ red dots where $3 \le m \le 6$.

$\hspace0.5in$ [image: A bunch of examples]

- **Case 1.** $m = 3$

  There are $\binom{n}{3}$ ways to pick $3$ red dots $\{ a, b, c \}$ out of $n$ red dots. WOLOG, we can assume $1 \le a < b < c \le n $. Given $a, b, c$, it is clear every red dot is shared by $2$ lines and there is only one way to form a triangle with the three lines $\{ ab, bc, ac \}$ (fig $1a$).

  This means there area $\binom{n}{3}$ triangles for $m = 3$.
- **Case 2.** $m = 4$,

  There are $\binom{n}{4}$ ways to pick $4$ red dots $\{ a, b, c, d \}$ out of $n$ red dots. WOLOG, we can assume $1 \le a < b < c < d \le n$. Given $a, b, c, d$, there are two possibilities, either one of them connects to all three lines (fig $2a$), this leads us nowhere or two of the red dots are shared by two lines. Consider the case
  $a$ is one of these two red dots and let's enumerate the possibilities:

  - $c$ is the other red dot, there are two possible line arrangements
    $\{ ac, cd, ab \}$ or $\{ ac, bc, ad \}$ (fig. $2b)$. However neither of them forms a triangle inside the circle.
  - $b$ is the other red dot, there are two possible line arrangements again
    $\{ ab, bc, ad \}$ (fig $2c$) and $\{ ab, bd, ac \}$ (fig $2d$). Only the second configuration forms a triangle inside the circle.
  - $d$ is the other red dot, this is similar to the above sub case with $d, a, b, c$ taking the roles of $a, b, c, d$. Among the two possible ine arrangements
    , only one of them forms a triangle inside the circle.
    If you loop over other possibilities of the two red dots which share lines.
    We find there are totally $4$ configuration for each choice of $(a, b, c, d)$.

  This means there are $4 \binom{n}{4}$ triangles for the $m = 3$ case.
- **Case 3.** $m = 5$

  There are $\binom{n}{5}$ ways to pick $5$ red dots $\{ a, b, c, d, e \}$ out of $n$ red dots. WOLOG, we can assume $1 \le a < b < c < d < e\le n$. Given $a, b, c, d, e $, it is clear one any only one of the red dots are shared by two lines. Consider the case $a$ is that distinguished red dots. There are six possible line arrangements
  $$
  \{ ab, ac, de \} (\text{fig } 3a),\quad
  \{ ab, ad, ce \} (\text{fig } 3b),\quad
  \{ ab, ae, cd \} (\text{fig } 3c),\\
  \{ ac, ad, be \} (\text{fig } 3d),\quad
  \{ ac, ae, bd \} (\text{fig } 3e),\quad
  \{ ad, ae, bc \} (\text{fig } 3f)
  $$
  and only of them $\{ ac, ad, be \}$ forms a triangle inside the circle.

  Since there are 5 possible ways to pick the distinguished red dots, there are
  $5\binom{n}{5}$ ways for the $m = 5$ case.
- **Case 4.** $m = 6$

  There are $\binom{n}{6}$ ways to pick $6$ red dots $\{ a, b, c, d, e, f \}$ out of $n$ red dots. WOLOG, we can assume $1 \le a < b < c < d < e < f\le n$. Given $a, b, c, d, e, f$, there are $15$ ways of grouping them into pairs and form $3$ lines. It is easy to see any line arrangement that contains neighboring pair $ab, bc, cd, de, ef, af$ does not form a triangle inside a circle (e.g. fig $4a$). This eliminate $11$ of them and we are left with $4$ line arrangements.
  $$\{ ac, be, df \},\quad \{ ad, be, cf \},\quad \{ ad, bf, ce \},\quad \{ ae, bd, cf \}$$
  If you draw these $4$ arrangements on a piece of paper, you will notice the $1^{st}$, $3^{rd}$ and $4^{th}$ arrangement all looks like fig $4b$. They also won't produce any triangle inside the circle.
  This leaves us with the $2^{nd}$ line arrangement $\{ ad, be, cf \}$. There are two possibilities. The 3 lines either form a triangle inside the circle (e.g. fig $4c$) or intersect at a single point. Since we have assumed the last case will not happen. This means for each choice of $\{ a, b, c, d, e, f \}$, there is one and only one way to join them to get a triangle.

  As a consequence, there are $\binom{n}{6}$ ways for the $m = 6$ case.

Combine these four cases, we can conclude the number of triangle for general $N$ is given by

$$\binom{n}{3} + 4\binom{n}{4} + 5\binom{n}{5} + \binom{n}{6}$$

**Part II** - maximum number of triangles remain after one remove 3 segments.

This is done by brute force. I write a program to locate all $644$ triangles
and proceed to check the effect on removing any one of the $28$ edges. 
Let $N_{ab}$ be the number of triangles destroyed when we remove the edge $ab$, we have

$$\begin{array}{r:l}
N_{ab} & ab\\
\hline
21  & 12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78, 18\\
66  & 13, 24, 35, 46, 57, 68, 17, 28\\
99  & 14, 25, 36, 47, 58, 16, 27, 38\\
111 & 15, 26, 37, 48
\end{array}$$

Since $3 \times 21 < \min(66,99,111)$, the configuration which maximize the number of triangles remain is formed by removing three consecutive edges on the perimeter of the circle (i.e those from the first row of above table).

Using rotational symmetry, we can assume $18$ is one of the three edges to go.
We only need to go through $\binom{7}{2} = 21$ pairs of edges from the set $\{ 12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78 \}$ to identify the optimal configurations.

Comment: +1 great answer. It seems then that the choice of $6$ dots dominates as $n$ gets very large. Also, it looks like your method generalises beyond just triangles: to quadrilaterals, pentagons. Probably have to be convex though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Part II is 644-(21*3-2)=583？

Comment: @Dori yes. When you remove two edges on the perimeter, the two sets of destroyed triangles are disjoint unless they are next to each other. This is the source of the extra $2$ in your formula

Answer (score 2):

**Not an answer** - just an upper bound.

Notice that every triangle in the figure contains exactly three edges in the graph. And $3$ edges can form at most $1$ triangle. So an upper bound for this quantity is:

$$e \choose 3$$

where $e = {8 \choose 2}$.

### Sketch Argument

Further notice that no 3 lines are parallel. Therefore, any choice of 3 lines must intersect *somewhere*. The number of triangles in the figure is then the number of sets of three lines whose 3 intersection points lie within the octagon. Perhaps this is an easier problem to solve. Perhaps we can tighten the bound. I conjecture that a lower bound is at least

$$\frac14 {e \choose 3}$$

because there can be either $0, 1, 2, 3$ intersection points within the octagon, and I feel that there can hardly be more outside than inside. Admittedly, this is just my gut instinct talking.

Comment: As you've presumably just noticed, there are pairs of edges which do not intersect so choosing any 3 edges doesn't necessarily give a triangle. It's certainly a valid upper bound though.

Comment: Yep, it had that "too good to be true" feel. Still, at least it's an upper bound. Phew. I wonder if closed form is even possible...

Answer (score 1):

Hint:Have you found out the total number of lines in the picture?

If not find it By adding the number of sides of the polygon and the diagonals.Find number of diagonals using the formula {$n\choose 2$-$n$} where $n$ is the number of sides in the polygon.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this hint e.g. how does it help us towards finding the total number of triangles?

Comment: @ColmBhandal-Use the fact that for every line inside the polygon two triangles can be formed that are found on either side of it and for and line making up the side there is one triangle that can be formed with it.Be sure to eliminate the common triangles.

Comment: tatan Unfortunately I am still struggling to understand your argument :(. Perhaps if you spell it out in a slightly more mathematical way I will be able to follow it.

Answer (score 1):

**not quite a correct answer, see comments**

We can choose any triangle by:

1. Select one edge of the graph (ie between 2 red nodes).
2. Select any two points on that edge, either the red nodes or the intersections.
3. The two points selected form one side of a triangle.
4. Each triangle can be identified by 3 mini line segments so we can divide by 3.

There are 8 points and therefore 8 edges of each of several types.

8 of the edges are between consecutive nodes so they only have 2 points and give rise to 1 segment.

8 of the edges are between nodes separated by 2 sides, these have 7 points (2 ends, plus the edges between the intermediate node and the 5 remaining ones) and thus 7×6=42 segments.

8 of the edges are between nodes separated by 3 sides, these have 10 points (2 ends, plus the edges between the 2 intermediate nodes and the 4 remaining ones) and thus 10×9=90 segments.

4 of the edges are between nodes separated by 4 sides, these have 11 points (2 ends, plus the edges between the 3 nodes on one side and the 3 on the other) and thus 11×10=110 segments.

Total = 8 + 8×42 + 8×90 + 4×110 = 440+720+336+8 = 1504

*this doesn't divide by 3 so there must be something wrong, see comments*

Whether there's a closed form for the n-noded case, i don't know. I suspect there would be at least a difference between odd and even numbers.

Comment: Bravo - did you divide by 3 in the end?

Comment: Oh no. I think there's a problem here. :( I think you are counting "segments" between adjacent points but omitting segments between non-adjacent points? That is, it seems like you've counted only triangles that don't contain other triangles. I'd appreciate your thoughts on this. A pity, I initially thought it was a clever approach.

Comment: @ColmBhandal Thanks - no I didn't, and 1504 isn't divisible by 3 so there must still be something wrong :(

Comment: I think some of the line segments from the later edges (from nodes 3 or 4 sides apart) don't form triangles. Can't just take any two junctions on those. Will have a think about it.

Comment: @ColmBhandal that's not it, i was counting any pair of points on each edge, therefore any segment - but unfortunately a few of these segments particularly in the middle don't form the edge of a triangle.

Comment: aha- not all segments are part of triangles. Seems like we're running into similar counting difficulties!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29440/discussion-between-colm-bhandal-and-ianf1).

Comment: Love to, unfortunately chat login not working on my phone. Think i'm very close though. Just the junctions of the order 3 and order 4 edges need a little attention.