# Count triangles in a pentagon with all of its diagonals drawn

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

How many triangles in this picture?

[image: pentagon_with_diagonals]

I am able to count one by one, but it takes long time. I wonder whether there is an easy way or systematic way to count. Thank you.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447793/how-many-triangles-are-there-in-the-picture/1447990#1447990

Answer (score 2):

Break into cases:

- all three vertices of the triangle are on the outer pentagon
- two of the three vertices are adjacent on the outer pentagon while the third is in the inner pentagon
- two of the three vertices are nonadjacent on the outer pentagon while the third is in the inner pentagon
- only one of the three vertices are on the outer pentagon

In case 1, any choice of three distinct vertices will form a triangle, so case 1 contributes $\binom{5}{3}=10$ to the overall sum.

In case 2, notice that any choice of two distinct vertices from the outer pentagon will have a two choices of a third vertex from the inner pentagon such that the three form a triangle in the image.  The number of adjacent pairs is $5$, each of which contributing three to the sum, for a total of $15$ being contributed.

[image]

In case 3, notice that any choice of two distinct vertices from the outer pentagon will have a unique choice of a third vertex from the inner pentagon such that the three form a triangle in the image.  The number of nonadjacent pairs is $5$, each of which contributing one to the sum.

[image]

In case 4, notice that any choice of single vertex from the outer pentagon has a unique pair of vertices from the inner pentagon such that the three form a triangle in the image.  Thus, case 3 contributes $\binom{5}{1}=5$ to the overall sum.

[image]

Finally, notice that no other triangles exist in the image.

This brings the overall sum to $10+15+5+5=35$

Comment: Please check the second case.  For each side of the outer pentagon, there are two scalene triangles in which the third vertex is in the interior pentagon and one isosceles triangle in which the third vertex is in the interior pentagon.

Comment: @N.F. Corrected.  Included images as well.  I think I absentmindedly mixed cases one and two in my mind when looking for triangles which shared an edge with the outer pentagon.

Comment: It is a good (and nicely illustrated) answer.  Alas, the OP's other question indicated that she or he is a middle school student, so I would not be surprised if the OP asks you questions about your use of binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

We use casework. First, we count the number of triangles with all three vertices on the pentagon. Notice that any set of three points on the pentagon will form a triangle. Therefore, here we have $\dbinom{5}{3} = 10$ triangles. Now we count the number of triangles with one or more vertices in the interior of the pentagon. We count this manually - there are $5$ small isosceles triangles, $10$ scalene triangles, and $5$ large isosceles triangles. This is a total of $10 + 5 + 10 + 5 + 5 = \boxed{35}$ triangles.

Comment: Be careful.  $\binom{5}{3} = 10$.

Comment: There are $35$ triangles, but you failed to list five of the isosceles triangles.  Observe that $10 + 5 + 10 + 5 = 30$.

Answer (score 0):

Ordering the $10$ vertices from top to bottom, and in rows left-to-right, the adjacency matrix of this graph is

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The trace of the third power of this matrix is $330$, and this counts the triangles in the graph, each six times, giving $55$ triangles But this also counts triangles whose vertices are collinear. This happens when all three vertices are on the same one of the five sides of the “star.” Each star side contains four vertices, so there are ${4\choose3}=4$ such triangles on each of the five star sides. Subtracting these $4\times5=20$ degenerate triangles from the $55$ triangles in the graph leaves $35$ triangles.

Comment: Your method seems simple. Thank you for help. But I don't understand how you get the matrix and had a little hard time to understand your explanation. I am a middle school student.